# How to mock SMBConnection class to return mock connection object

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, pysmb

I have a function that returns smb.SMBConnection object.

In **my_module.py**

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

def get_connection(user, pwd, server):
    return SMBConnection(user, pwd, socket.gethostname(), server, use_ntlm_v2=True)
```

I am trying to use `mock.patch`

```
@mock.patch(‘smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection’)

def test_get_connection(self, mock_class):
    self.assertEquals(mock_class, my_module.get_connection)
```

But this doesn’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example here,

```
#from mod1.conn import conn
# the import above won't work with patch !

# Make a folder mod1 and a sub-folder conn.
# Create a __init__.py inside both.
# Inside the __init__.py of sub-folder conn
# define conn = 100

import mod1

import unittest
from unittest import mock, main, TestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock

def func():
    return mod1.conn.conn

class MyTests(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('mod1.conn.conn')
    def test1(self, mock1):
        self.assertEqual(func(), mock1)
        self.assertIsInstance(func(), Mock)

print(func())  # prints 100
unittest.main() # runs test OK
```

Comment: So mod1.con.con is fake mock ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Yes. I changed the example a little bit to make it more clear. Just consider `mod1` is `smb`, and `mod1.conn.conn` is `smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection` in your case. Yes when the test runs `mod1.conn.conn`, instead of having the value 100 from a normal run it is now a Mock object. That means the patch is working. The test still runs OK with the new second assert.

Comment: I did the same but I get assertion error: `<smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection instance at 0x1f5eb90> != <MagicMock name=‘SMBConnection’ id=‘40493008’>`

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz can you please update your question by adding the code you are currently using and still does not work?